# Provide command line switch after xargs output

Tags: xargs, arguments

Given I use this command:

`outputStuff.sh | awk -F"-" '{print $5"-"$6}' | xargs someTool (XARGS OUTPUT HERE) --someCommandLineSwitchHere`

However I need to provide command line switch after the xargs output? Anybody tackled this problem yet?

Answer (score 2):

So the flag is for `someTool` but must come after the input files...using a subshell gives you all kinds of flexibility:

```
xargs sh -c 'someTool "$@" --someCommandLineSwitchHere' someTool
```

After `xargs` processing this effectively becomes

```
xargs sh -c 'someTool "$@" --someCommandLineSwitchHere' someTool item1 item2 ... itemN
```

...and everything on the command line after the single quoted string becomes input arguments to `sh` (positional parameters). These start at `$0` and since `$0` is usually the command being run we just use `someTool` (though anything is allowed here). Everything remaining is added by `xargs` and are your normal positional parameters: `$1`, `$2`, and so on.